# How to enable/disable different ethernet cards for different Windows users?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I need help setting up different ethernet cards for different Windows users.

Situation:

- LAN: a wired network and an extra wireless interface/subnet (for public access)
- a computer running Windows 7 with two ethernet cards (one wired, one wireless) and two users. This PC must be ready to use anytime for any of both users
- User A (administrator) needs access to the wired network. User B (standard) needs access to the wireless network (and MUST NOT access the wired one)

I just want to let the users start session and be connected to their respective net. That's why I tought about enabling/disabling each PCI card for each user, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Since both MACs must be enabled anytime, I cannot configure it through router rules (pfSense). Can I do it using Windows policy group?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Lifehacker is really not my first choice of reference, but since it is number one on the Google results for *"windows force user to wired connection or wireless"*  I think it appropriate.

- Go to Network Connections under the Control Panel
- Under the file menu, go to Advanced > Advanced Settings
- In the Adapters and Bindings tab, click on the connection you want prioritized (e.g., the ethernet connection) and use the up arrow to move it to the top of the list

http://lifehacker.com/force-windows-to-use-your-wired-connection-instead-of-w-482614663

Additionally, you can select which wireless network a specific user should be restricted to.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43782/how-to-enable-user-specific-wireless-networks-in-windows-7/

In short, use Network Settings.